# Can we control the speed of the Scrollview

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a scroll view (shown in the picture below).  It allows the user to jump/navigate between various sections in my app. The number of sections varies between 20 to 40 (which is pretty large). The speed of the scroll should depend on the speed with which the user swipes/scrolls on the view. I thought of doing this operation by using the `contentOffSet` property of `scrollview`, but didn't do it as it might decrease the usability of this feature.

[image]-------> This is the scroll view

**1-How can I control the speed of the scroll view?**

**2-Can I do this operation with out the help of content offset property?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on your custom view and use `velocityInView`:

If that doesn't cut your need, do your own customized calculation by listening to `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`